# Finding the largest roots of a polynomial in R

Tags: r, polynomials

Is there a way to avoid the complex numbers in

polyroot {base} ?

The help file says: "…polyroot returns the n-1 complex zeros", but I simply need the largest root of a quadratic equation and the complex numbers are too much of a good thing here. Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

When you use this you set the return against an object, say

```
roots=polyroot(coefs)
```

and you can then return the real ones by excluding the imaginary ones via `complex::Im()`

```
which(Im(roots)==0)
```

Comment: You should not use exact comparisons for floating point numbers. `abs(Im(roots))<1e-12)` should be more exact in most of the cases, since `x^2-2*x+1+1e-20=0` is impossible to represent in `double` floating point.

Answer (score 1):

If you get complex solutions for a quadratic equation, then there are no real roots.

The largest root of the equation `x²+px+q` is

```
(-p+sqrt(p*p-4*q))/2
```

if the term inside the square root is non-negative.

Or did you mean a root of largest magnitude?